# The first page has a different bottom margin from the rest of the text. I can't figure how to make them look the same. Can anyone help me?

Tags: geometry, article

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,top=40mm,right=25mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{images/logouerj.jpg}}
\rhead{
Example\\
Example\\
Example\\
Example}

\title{\vspace{0.5cm}\centering Work}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

Comment: I changed the example to `example-image` so I could run it and got the warning `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 56.18335pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.`  so the inconsistent layout is expected, do you get that warning?